# clicking a JPanel inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So I have a `JFrame`, in which it has a bunch of `JPanel` which is called `venPanel`. When I click on a `venPanel` I want the `JFrame` to add a new `JPanel` to the east of the layout (because the `JFrame` uses the border layout). How can I achieve this in my `venPanel` class? Currently the `mouseClick` action listener for the `venPanel` is implemented as:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    try {
        GUIVenDetails vendetail = new GUIVenDetails(ven);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Where `GUIVenDetails` is the `JPanel` I wanted to add to the east of the `JFrame`..
I hope the question is clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
JPanel source = (JPanel)event.getSource();
JPanel parent = (JPanel)source.getParent();
parent.add(anotherPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
parent.revalidate();
```

Comment: Yes and consider `remove` ing any existing `GUIVenDetails` from the `JFrame`, before adding a new one,  if this event occurs a second time?

Answer (score 3):

Or you could add a `JPanel` to the EAST that uses a `CardLayout` and then swap `JPanels` in that spot by calling the `CardLayout` methods.